# Set theory problem with the inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

I started learning set theory, but as for the begin firstly I'm having problems with some notations.
From the lectures we learned about this principle which is as following:

1.$$ |A \cup B|= |A|+|B|$$
The problem with this one is that I don't know where to use it?

EDIT: This part till here has been understood!

Second, from the inclusion and exclusion principle I'm trying to solve these two examples which are:

1. Given:
   $$
    |A \cup B \cup C|=45 \\
    |A \cap C|=5 \\
    |A \cap B|=4 \\
   |B \cap C|=6 \\
    |A \setminus (B \cup C)|=10 \\
    |B \setminus (A \cup C)|=12 \\
    |C \setminus (B \cup A)|=12 $$

Find $|A \cap B \cap C|=?$

2. Given:
   $$|A \cap B \cap C|=3 \\
     |C|=12 \\ 
   |A \setminus (B \cup C)|=10 \\ 
   |B \setminus C|=17 \\
   |A|=21 \\ 
   |U|=49 \\ 
   |B \cap C|=5 \\ 
   |A \cap C|=5 \\
   $$

a) Find:
$$|C \setminus (A \cup B)|=?$$
b) Find:
$$|A \cup (B \cup C)|=?$$

Where $|U| $is the universal set.

I tried using Venn Diagram but it isn't bringing me far, just the first step of organizing the sets.

P.S I have other examples that I must solve but I think knowing how these work may help me with the others.

Comment: The first equation is false;  true iff A,B are disjoint.

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion principle is not |A∪B|=|A|+|B|
 But it is |A∪B|=|A|+|B|-|A∩B|
Can you solve it now?

Comment: I know the formula Linda, but I don't know how to solve those problems. Thank you William for explaining the first question.

Comment: I don't think your problem 1 has a unique solution as stated.  Are you sure you have stated the problem correctly and haven't left anything out?

Comment: The first one was just something that I misunderstood so it doesn't have to do with the second one for which the first one doesn't apply because they aren't disjoint. So in the begin I thought I could use it to solve the problem. Therefore ignore the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We  partition the  set  $A\cup B\cup C$ into $7$ pairwise disjoint sets

\begin{align*}
A\cup B\cup C&=\left(A\setminus (B\cup C)\right) \cup \left(B\setminus (C\cup A)\right)  \cup \left(C\setminus (A\cup B)\right) \\
&\qquad\cup \left((A\cap B)\setminus C\right) \cup \left((B\cap C)\setminus A\right) \cup \left((C\cap A)\setminus B\right) \\
&\qquad\cup (A\cap B\cap C)
\end{align*}

[image]

The strategy  is to  derive  relations consisting solely of one or more of these $7$ *atomic* subsets and obtain this way the results.

We have
\begin{align*}
|A\cup B\cup C|&=|A\setminus (B\cup C)| + |B\setminus (C\cup A)|  + |C\setminus (A\cup B)| \\
&\qquad+ |(A\cap B)\setminus C| + |(B\cap C)\setminus A| + |(C\cap A)\setminus B|\tag{1} \\
&\qquad+ |A\cap B\cap C|
\end{align*}

> **First problem:**
>
> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> |A \cup B \cup C|&=45\\
> |A \setminus (B \cup C)|&=10\\
> |B \setminus (A \cup C)|&=12\\
> |C \setminus (B \cup A)|&=12
> \end{align*}
>    we obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> 45&=10+12+12\\
> &+ |(A\cap B)\setminus C| + |(B\cap C)\setminus A| + |(C\cap A)\setminus B| \\
> &\qquad+ |(A\cap B\cap C)|\\
> 11&=|(A\cap B)\setminus C| + |(B\cap C)\setminus A| + |(C\cap A)\setminus B| \\
> &\qquad+ |A\cap B\cap C|\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $|A\cap B|=4, |A\cap C|=5$ and  $|B\cap C|=6$ we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> |A\cap B|&= |(A\cap B)\setminus C| + |A\cap B\cap C|=4\\
> |A\cap C|&= |(C\cap A)\setminus B| + |A\cap B\cap C|=5\tag{3}\\
> |B\cap C|&= |(B\cap C)\setminus A| + |A\cap B\cap C|=6
> \end{align*}
>
> Combining (2)  and (3) we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> 11&=(4-|A\cap B\cap C|)+(5-|A\cap B\cap C|)+(6-|A\cap B\cap C|)+|A\cap B\cap C|
> \end{align*}
>
> We finally conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{|A\cap B\cap C|=2}
> \end{align*}

Comment: I'm really thankful for you help. You helped me solve even the others! Many many thanks again.

Comment: @NoraIbrahimi: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for two sets is
$$
|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|
$$
and for three sets is
$$
|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|
$$

---

We are given
$$
 |A \cup B \cup C|=45 \\
 |A \cap C|=5 \\
 |A \cap B|=4 \\
|B \cap C|=6\\
 |A \setminus (B \cup C)|=10 \\
 |B \setminus (A \cup C)|=12 \\
 |C \setminus (B \cup A)|=12
$$
For any $A,B,C$, we have $A\cap(B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$ and therefore, Inclusion-Exclusion says that
$$
|A\cap(B\cup C)|=|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|-|A\cap B\cap C|
$$
Also, because $A\cap(B\cup C)$ is disjoint from $A\setminus(B\cup C)$,
$$
|A\cap(B\cup C)|=|A|-|A\setminus(B\cup C)|
$$
Combining the last two equations gives
$$
|A|+|A\cap B\cap C|=|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|A\setminus(B\cup C)|
$$
Thus, in particular, reading the blue terms from those given,
$$
\begin{align}
|A|+|A\cap B\cap C|
&=\color{#00F}{|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|A\setminus(B\cup C)|}=19\\
|B|+|A\cap B\cap C|
&=\color{#00F}{|B\cap C|+|B\cap A|+|B\setminus(C\cup A)|}=22\\
|C|+|A\cap B\cap C|
&=\color{#00F}{|C\cap A|+|C\cap B|+|C\setminus(A\cup B)|}=23
\end{align}
$$
Summing the last three equations gives
$$
|A|+|B|+|C|+3|A\cap B\cap C|=64
$$
Inclusion-Exclusion gives
$$
\begin{align}
45
&=|A\cup B\cup C|\\
&=\color{#C00}{|A|+|B|+|C|}\color{#090}{-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|}\color{#C00}{+|A\cap B\cap C|}\\
&=\color{#C00}{64}\color{#090}{-15}\color{#C00}{-2|A\cap B\cap C|}
\end{align}
$$
Algebra then gives
$$
|A\cap B\cap C|=2
$$